# how to include group by column in result dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

how to have main_column or the group by column included in the result as now in the result dataframe only two columns present

```
def customFunction(x):
    values = {
        'col1': x['another_column'].count(),
        'col2': x['another_column'].sum()}

    return pd.Series(values, index=['col1', 'col2'])

Df = Df.groupby('main_column' ).apply(customFunction)
```

Comment: Instead of reassigning to `Df`, you need to concat or join, or assign them explicitly to new columns

Comment: @user3483203 thanks , then I will do the join ,one help how to include the groupby column in the result as now its only have two columns

Comment: Please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by below

```
 Df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```